# 400 bad request for http post request in .NET MVC API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've read many tutorials but I can't figure it out why I get a 400 bad request on a Post request.

My Api controller:

```
public class CategoryApiController : ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("get")]
    public int GetSomething () {
        return 1;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("post")]
    public string PostSomething (int id) {
        return "2";
    }
}
```

My routes:

```
routes.MapRoute (
            "ControllerOnly",
            "api/{controller}"
            );

        routes.MapRoute (
            "ControllerAndId",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new {
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute (
            "ControllerAndActionAndId",
            "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {
                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                action = "AddSomething"
            }
        );
```

And my ajax request :

```
$('#click').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/CategoryApi/get',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#raspuns').text(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
});

$('#raspuns').click(function () {
    $(this).text("nimic");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/CategoryApi/post',
        type: 'POST',
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'id': 1
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#click').text(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
});
```

So the GET request works fine but the POST request return a 400 status. The explicit message from the post request :

```
{"Message": "The request is invalid.", "MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-  nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String PostSomething(Int32)' in  'stackoverflow.Controllers.CategoryApiController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a   nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}
```

The request body contains id:1. So I sent the id as parameter.

Get request is sent to the first method as expected but I don't understand why the Post request isn't working.

EDIT: So what I want is to have full control over which method is invoked in a particular controller. In JAVA, you just specify the url above the desired method and that method will be invoked when the url in accessed. I really don't understand how do I do that in .NET MVC with routes. I want to have in a single controller many GET and POST methods. Can someone give me an example or a good tutorial? 
PS: I've read some tutorials but there wasn't what I want.

Comment: Can you provide what your request body looks like. The error indicates that you are not providing the expected argument to your method.

Comment: Why is your Action "AddSomething"? Isn't the method PostSomething?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that the parameter on the actual `PostSomething` method is not optional. You need to either set a default value, or make it nullable.

Examples:

```
public string PostSomething (int? id) {
```

or

```
public string PostSomething (int id = -1) {
```

Alternatively, if you want the id to be required, you need to update the call to match the route:

```
$('#raspuns').click(function () {
    $(this).text("nimic");
    $.ajax({
        // Since your route is "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        // add the id to the url
        url: '/api/CategoryApi/post/1',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#click').text(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
});
```

I don't remember enough JS to make the id a variable in the URL string.

Comment: You are right. If I make the id nullable it works fine. But how can I force a not null id. I've removed id = UrlParameter.Optional from my route and with int? id works, but if I make id not null again the 400 request status apears again. I want at parameter to be sent to that post method and from that json I will create an object.

Comment: Added a different api call using the matching route

Comment: If you want to put it in the body, you should check out the tutorial at http://tech.pro/tutorial/1285/building-rest-api-with-mvc-4-web-api-part-1, part-2 gets into parameter binding.

Comment: The reason for POST is to not add data in the url. With GET you append data to url like this url?id=1. But with post you send data encoded in the request.

Comment: No, POST is just the Method. You can do a post with all information in the URI. If you wish to ask how to send and process data in the body of a JSON request for ASP.NET MVC, you should really check the tutorial I posted.